# ¿Cómo actualizar datos con LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

No se si el termino actualizar datos con `LEFT JOIN` es correcto, porque en realidad lo estoy usando para una condición `WHERE`.

He revisado la siguiente pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335388/update-and-left-outer-join-statements

He usado uno de los ejemplos publicados de la siguiente manera, ejecutando directamente en SQL:

```
UPDATE tbl_branch_office
        SET id_enterprise=1,
            business_name='prueba'
        FROM tbl_branch_office b
        LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac ON b.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
        WHERE b.id_branch_office=1 AND ac.id_user=2
```

Pero me sale error:

> Existe un error en su sintaxis SQL; revise el manual que se corresponde con su versión del servidor MariaDB para averiguar la sintaxis correcta a utilizar cerca de 'FROM tbl_branch_office b

Este es mi código con MYSQL con PHP:

```
    $stmtIIE = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_branch_office
                                        SET id_enterprise=?,
                                            business_name=?,
                                            ruc=?,
                                            tradename=?,
                                            establishment=?,
                                            country=?,
                                            city=?,
                                            state=?,
                                            address=?,
                                            phone=?,
                                            email=?,
                                            active=?
                                        FROM tbl_branch_office b
                                        LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac ON b.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
                                        WHERE b.id_branch_office=?
                                        AND ac.id_user=?");
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta en la que te estás inspirando es `SQL server`, no sé si esa sintaxis sea correcta ahí, no conozco mucho de `SQL Server` pero en `MariaDB` parece redundante poner un `update` con un `from`

Intenta con

```
UPDATE tbl_branch_office b
LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac
    ON b.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
SET id_enterprise=1,
    business_name='prueba'
WHERE b.id_branch_office=1 AND ac.id_user=2
```

También es importante para evitar errores de campos duplicados entre tablas, que pongas de que tabla son los campos, por ejemplo `SET b.id_enterprise=1, ...` o `SET ac.id_enterprise=1, ..`

Comment: No es `SQL Server` amigo solo que en `phpmyadmin` cuando quieres probar algún código de consulta existe una opción que dice `SQL` pero es exactamente `MariaDB`. Gracias por responder, ya verificó:)